# Where can I find an easy-to-follow transition recipe for an iphone developer looking to switch to working on android phones?

Tags: java, iphone, android, ios

I'm looking for a guide for development on the Android which is specifically aimed at expert iPhone developers - where can I find a quality one, online or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this isn't what you asked for, but if you are in fact an "expert iPhone Developer," then just reading a couple manuals on the Android dev page should allow you to have no problem jumping into the Android platform.

The developer docs (manuals) that I highly recommend are:

1. [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
   [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
   [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Secondly, even if you do find some manuals specific to what your after, I would *still* read these 3 manuals because they explain the topics so well.  After reading these I'm sure you'll start to understand the "Android lingo," be able to draw the comparison to iPhone, and be well on your way to superb Android apps in no time.